# Is the symfony2 entity field a good solution for many related objects?

Tags: forms, symfony, tags, entity

Is it an nice solution to use the symphony entity form type for relations (for example tags - manytomany).

I think of a big collection of tag - objects! Is it not to much overhead to load all the tags of the database for a choice - list?

And if this is true, how could I solve this issue better?

Greetings Michael!

Answer (score 0):

You should not care about micro optimizations in this state. But of course, you should know Doctrine. If you have an entitity with a one to many or many to many relation and you know, you need it the releations, e.g. your tags as getTags, later in your application, you should do a join in the query builder. Otherwise the relation is lazy loaded on the first call to `getTags`

Answer (score 0):

`tags - manytomany` is a normal solution, but of course it is an overhead to load all the tags of the database for a choicelist (if there is a large collection), you don't need to load all of them at once, use some jquery plugin to handle it instead (may be ajaxbased Select2 plugin...)

Comment: Ok. That was what I was trying first. But it is not possible to set the choices option to null or empty array. In this case all the tags will be loaded again.

Comment: @Slowwie You don't need to create a select list even, you can create a textfield which converts id to object (with DataTransformer) and use jquery plugin to add autocomplete feature, [bootstrap-ajax-typeahead](https://github.com/biggora/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead) can be good option..

Comment: Yes I know. I was trying this before all. But it has its own drawbacks. For example you have no id's available in the reverseTransform function. Then I have to make a doctrine call on every string checking for existing in the database and persist new tags and so on. I don't think this is a clean and nice solution when I have a nice and easy form type like 'entity type' of symfony2. is there an option to disable the loading of choices in the entity type and load it afterwards in the template with Ajax ?

Comment: @Slowwie This is not a FormComponent's job, you should create such a type by extending the existing one by yourself.

Comment: Ok. This sounds good. Can you give an example or usefull links?